# How to create Secure WCF Service for intranet application?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I have one intranet WCF application. But my services are not secure. If someone will know the URL of services and proper methods they can access service and find out data through service.

How can I apply security at service level?

Comment: You mean - if someone in you intranet will know the URL?

Comment: Yes. If someone over intranet will know the url he can access my services and wsdl

Comment: There are many tutorials about securing WCF services. You can start from [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx)

Comment: I went through http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/ articles but I am not able to decide which one should I use. If you have idea Can you suggest some? I am new to WCF application

Comment: And how is your WCF consumed by default?

Comment: It is consumed by MVC application. But I don't want to go on consumer part. I want security at Service level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64245/discussion-between-learner-and-konrad-kokosa).